# Generating RDP file on the fly

Tags: remote-desktop, terminal-services, rdp

I want to create a web application similar to TS Web Access, where I can create rdp files on the fly for Remote Apps configured on the server. Any idea??

Answer (score 2):

We had to do this exact thing.

```
private void InvokeRDPSign(String fileName, String certificateThumbPrint)
{
    Process signingProcess = new Process();
    signingProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"rdpsign.exe";

    String arguments = String.Format("/sha1 {0} {1}", certificateThumbPrint, fileName);
    signingProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
    signingProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    signingProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    signingProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Environment.SystemDirectory;
    signingProcess.Start();

    String signingOutput = signingProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    signingProcess.WaitForExit();
    int exitCode = signingProcess.ExitCode;
    //TODO:  should we throw an error if the exitcode is not 0
}
```

Be aware that that the RDPSign.exe is different on each version of windows. You will find that an older version of the utility will ignore newer settings from the signature.

Comment: I had to use an elevated account for the app pool identity to make this work. As other posts have suggested, I'm probably going to move this code to a service on the machine with elevated privileges rather than permanently changing the app pool identity.

Answer (score 1):

well Having looked at a 'rdp' file this is the contents:

```
screen mode id:i:2
desktopwidth:i:1280
desktopheight:i:768
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:2,3,1430,104,2230,704
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
displayconnectionbar:i:1
disable wallpaper:i:1
disable full window drag:i:1
allow desktop composition:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s: [YOUR IP]
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:0
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:1
drivestoredirect:s:
```

Just create that as a string, seems straightforward.

ps I have no idea what the 'winposstr' parameter is...

Comment: this is perfectly fine, but my remoteapps are digitally signed with a certificate, which adds 2 additional parameters in my rdp file:
1. signscope:s
2. signature:s

How can I create values for these parameters, these are using SHA1 hash...???

Comment: I don't know whats going on with these certs. can't you create a valid 'remote application' RDP and then copy that sig? or is the sig different each time?

Comment: Signature is same everytime, but i hv to open diff. app on diff buttons, and signature depends on the remote app program name, so i hv to change the signature on the fly. Sample rdp file content:

Comment: span monitors:i:1
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
server port:i:3389
allow font smoothing:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:1
authentication level:i:0
gatewayusagemethod:i:2
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
gatewaycredentialssource:i:0
full address:s:LUTRONTS1
alternate shell:s:||TSClient_TS2
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||TSClient_TS2
gatewayhostname:s:
remoteapplicationname:s:TSClient_TS2
remoteapplicationcmdline:s:

Comment: signscope:s:Full Address,Server Port,GatewayHostname,GatewayUsageMethod,GatewayProfileUsageMethod,GatewayCredentialsSource,PromptCredentialOnce,Alternate Shell,RemoteApplicationProgram,RemoteApplicationMode,RemoteApplicationName,RemoteApplicationCmdLine,Authentication Level,RedirectDrives,RedirectPrinters,RedirectCOMPorts,RedirectSmartCards,RedirectPOSDevices,RedirectClipboard,DevicesToRedirect,DrivesToRedirect

Comment: signature:s:AQABAAEAAACVBAAAMIIEkQYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIEgjCCBH4CAQExCzAJBgUrDgMC  GgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEHAaCCAvowggL2MIIB3qADAgECAhCMel1Y/5YAjUXCeMhU  Fzi8MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMCQxIjAgBgNVBAMTGWx1dHJvbnRzMS5nZ24ubmFn  YXJyby5jb20wHhcNMDkxMTE5MDc0NTIyWhcNMTAxMTE4MDAwMDAwWjAkMSIwIAYD  VQQDExlsdXRyb250czEuZ2duLm5hZ2Fycm8uY29tMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF  AAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAn+ExkAWD10vOi0TDOyZl9XGuh6Q7qSKVTzaumgUx1S88  H3KS8wLgO6eWThGKaFzLhPhO98G6RRbtxcdcSjeP+3RSQPNA8chbYZ5I3zhPQ8J3  D1d7fvdgWodL+ltvrnTMr0cxZWGR5xtCljwqcKhoUDHnPJQiU9g2WGhs7PqmPOFA

Comment: QtFrHUo1hrHyawYWfqekNhVnWtyI0xxnM3rpnwile6LWJAPGPYolHc/qTV9NaLwq  7c3a4NfshM24UN7WUo/0I4pnHbwjjyUHWxCDOQPO5nRGGmVdFh2Jwn5F+P82qLUE  TvT2vJJ0tRn/TEMXZEEMOztBEONN9QtKhaRI+2HJdwIDAQABoyQwIjALBgNVHQ8E  BAMCBDAwEwYDVR0lBAwwCgYIKwYBBQUHAwEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAEDj  cor3tOY/4JnwNuQxOWbdV2yIW/gITWsJXpkM6X+0XcFTKHtPjmthGphwxAniiw7D  rgpBokzh/8tRNMIZDeQej+JkgYLKO4Q+fzBhvxz4qHQqYZlSVPwBhcjrPFK88ggo  JqYh2JTAttC5V969YMOVYc//OAKLoVMravaHUmlRAC6NvkHiVV+HoeDZbAQwnQaa  zNpMwy1A6Mre6hQI4NsCFOaZEeJwtTuvd8RgpIdzI3oNL5Vy2dfXj9dvSu8OtrPU  r2Kk34gEhC6a/owFSQOc208WJfOvX0G1TFKl8Tyx6vcgqWfohlUNDAxxd68Fl22f

Comment: R0EANq3XNPjp4aoyn74xggFfMIIBWwIBATA4MCQxIjAgBgNVBAMTGWx1dHJvbnRz  MS5nZ24ubmFnYXJyby5jb20CEIx6XVj/lgCNRcJ4yFQXOLwwCQYFKw4DAhoFADAN  BgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAQAsjUwyBxFpBHFTCFKJixLIZoOb2HK0/hu/vWNeIOfe  fJ9OakxSzzHYYRZSrWKCbcl3Mp1/La1/D7L9vXlotPMB3qzeT5voczxLrY0J0Hly  08EALAYywbRki60brA2AKJ6Ri3ph3KUzD2aZQiV8kVZTJzqWPp20dCvL5Cl38qG6  I30ZtN1zadkgdg3vI0Ulh8IbfgNv9uQxvtGh9R55t8GRgTpexbGAx1r9ocKTSTW3  bFwds/l25ZKWrEiA1S+4r4J8QYLnoStVZcdOPBbp9z8CFfLxFoljA8pVVFqSQb51  PWV5+k2lqwBngp290Hoi6VL6HdXkA6eLYO8DqNuOJiFY

Comment: winposstr might be the client window position and size (top left point, bottom right point, width and height).

Comment: Yep, looks like it:  http://tiredblogger.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/changing-where-rdp-windows-open-on-the-screen/